# Argument 1 of Node.appendChild is not an object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have script that initiates a google map, i get no errors through the console upon initialization of the first instance of that function, though I have a link that resets the coordinates of the map to different stores, upon recalling the function with the new coordinates I get an Argument 1 of Node.appendChild is not an object. error for the following

```
    function CustomZoomControl(controlDiv, map) {
        //grap the zoom elements from the DOM and insert them in the map 
        var controlUIzoomIn= document.getElementById('cd-zoom-in'),
            controlUIzoomOut= document.getElementById('cd-zoom-out');
        controlDiv.appendChild(controlUIzoomIn);
        controlDiv.appendChild(controlUIzoomOut);

        // Setup the click event listeners and zoom-in or out according to the clicked element
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(controlUIzoomIn, 'click', function() {
            map.setZoom(map.getZoom()+1)
        });
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(controlUIzoomOut, 'click', function() {
            map.setZoom(map.getZoom()-1)
        });
    }

    var zoomControlDiv = document.createElement('div');
    var zoomControl = new CustomZoomControl(zoomControlDiv, map);
```

i cant figure out why the DOM object works fine in the first instance of the function but not when it is recalled

Comment: which line is giving this issue? also can you put `console.log(controlDiv)` before appending and after appending?

Comment: controlDiv.appendChild(controlUIzoomIn);
        controlDiv.appendChild(controlUIzoomOut);

Comment: How can two lines give error? JS execution will stop after first error itself

Comment: error is on line 
controlDiv.appendChild(controlUIzoomIn);

Comment: can you check if either of them is Not a valid Node? share the output of `console.log(controlDiv);console.log(controlUIzoomIn);` before the line that throws error.

Comment: // first instance of function this is the output on console
<div>
<div id="cd-zoom-in"> 
<div> 

// recall instance of the function
<div> 
null

Comment: So you are trying to append null to a Node, which is causing the problem

Comment: thank you, understood, so does the css need to be reloaded onclick to be able to pass that argument correctly as with the first initiation? cuz ive tried adjusting the code to only initialize that variable just once and it still wont work

Comment: perhaps if you can put more context to your question. I don't know what you mean by `css need to be reloaded onclick`

Comment: apologies... 

so basically the element 'cd-zoom-in' is being passed on page init with no problems and the zoom buttons are displayed on the map,

though for some reason which i cant figure out, when i click a link to change the location displayed by the map, it recalls the function and passes the null argument instead of the 'cd-zoom-in' argument like in the fist instance

Comment: can you show relevant markup and how this method is invoked?

Comment: the setMap function has the CustomZoomControl function nested in it, as mentioned it passes the arg in first instance, but when recalled as below it doesnt

//Reset map to new locations
 window.resetMap = function (newLatitude, newLongitude){
 
  setMap(newLatitude, newLongitude);
 }

Comment: i think i just need to figure out why it the ElementID is null when the function is recalled but not in the first instance

Comment: I have the opposite problem.. the id is null only in the first instance :(

Answer (score 1):

As per the comments above, `controlUIzoomIn` is `null`.

So, when you invoke [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) with `null` value as the argument then this error is thrown.

> Argument 1 of Node.appendChild is not an object

Comment: yes but why has that element ID become null upon recalling the script when it is not null on first call

Comment: @FaisalSadagah that is impossible to make out without looking at your attempt. Can you share a fiddle?

Comment: sure 
jsfiddle.net/5yyadcof/

Comment: @FaisalSadagah your main.js is not loading in the fiddle

Comment: i think i may have figured it out i need to recall another function from an external file that is editing my html and consequently the 'cd-zoom-in' element ID, without running it the element is null - basically calling on that function first before running the resetMap - will keep u posted on the outcome of this attempt

Answer (score 1):

couldnt figure out why it was giving me null - but i did know it was throwing an error upon recalling the function - somehow i didnt see this solution earlier but i just placed the original variable initialization outside the function and it worked